# Jquery Ajax request not saving cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, cross-domain, samesite

Iam sending ajax request with jquery from domain1 to domain2.

here is code:

```
let settings = {
        url: "https://domain2.com",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://domain1.com",
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    };
    jQuery.ajax(settings)
    .then( res => {
       // Do something with result
    );
```

but after request when iam checking browser cookies the response cookies not there.
iam also checked in network tab that domain2 sending the cookies.

anyone knows where is problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was my bad.

All the settings above was true, the issue was about domain2 that set the cookies

with attribute `SameSite = strict` so domian1 could not set these cookies.

More informations: [SameSite Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)

Answer (score -1):

Use in ajax settings:

```js
let settings = {
   url: "https://domain2.com",
   crossDomain: true,
   ... your settings
}
```